# UIColor with pattern image UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this code which sets one image:

```
NSArray *imageFilenames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"background iPad retina.png", @"iPad retina send.png", nil];

UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background iPad retina.png"]];
scroll1.backgroundColor = bgColor;
```

How can I set more images in the patter (from NSArray may be) so that I see one image then the other, then the first, then the second...

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not 100% sure, I think you can't do that by setting the backgroundColor, since `colorWithPatternImage` method will set a repeating image for the entire view.

Maybe you should set images to different `UIView`, then add them to the scroller one by one.